# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound for basic spring example

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I'm getting following error when i try to deploy the application in tomcat server.  Please help me solve this issue. localhost:8080/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/ is my home page and it is throwing the error.

Log Message:

```
  Aug 02, 2013 8:33:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;.
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:38 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:EnhancedRoyaltyTool' did not find a matching property.
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1007 ms
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:40 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:40 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Aug 02 20:33:40 CDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:40 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:41 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@196f4e87: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,viewResolver,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1391 ms
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\docs
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\examples
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@5a5f31b0')
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\host-manager
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\manager
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4363 ms
Aug 02, 2013 8:33:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
My web.xml file 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

My  dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.saas.royalties.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"  
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My SearchController.java

```
package com.saas.royalties.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class SearchController {

     @RequestMapping(value="/")
        public String printHelloWorld(ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("test", "test World!");
            System.out.println("test");
            return "hello";
        }

}
```

My pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.saas.royalty</groupId>
    <artifactId>EnhancedRoyaltyTool</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EnhancedRoyaltyTool Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring MVC depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>EnhancedRoyaltyTool</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

My folder structure ![Folder structure][1]

Comment: What actions do you take that give you that error message? Is it showing up on launch, on an HTTP GET, or something else?

Comment: I'm accessing the default homepage that is http:localhost:8080/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` in my dispatcher-servlet has fixed the issue

Comment: the reason is that Spring cannot find your controllers, add this into your xml configuration: <context:component-scan base-package="package.of.your.controllers"></context:component-scan>

Answer (score 2):

You told the servlet container in your `servlet-mapping` that you want the Spring Dispatcher attached to `/`, and you told Spring that the `printHelloWorld` method should be used to handle requests for `/` relative to the servlet base (which is just `/`). But then you're trying to load `/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/`, and you haven't told the servlet container or Spring to attach anything there. You can change the `RequestMapping` to `"/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/"`, move the entire Spring servlet to `"/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/*"` in the `servlet-mapping`, or just try visiting `http://localhost:8080/`.

Comment: I'm very new to spring but, I'm assuming that my pom has created war EndhancedRoyaltyTool and it is getting loaded by default as http:localhost:8080/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/  when i deploy the application

Comment: That depends on the how the container is set up. The fact that you're getting an error from Spring (instead of an error from the container) means that the container is pointing the request to Spring, but the fact that Spring is still seeing `EnhancedRoyaltyTool` in the path means that the request is relative to the servlet root, which must be `/`. You never did post your full error message, but am I correct in surmising you're getting a 404?

Comment: yes, I'm getting the 404 with requested resource not available error. It is same with localhost:8080/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/ .

Comment: If you're getting a 404 using the `/` URI, please print the whole error log for the request (not just the one line, but anything else that shows up at the same time).

Comment: Also, can you please verify that the `SearchController` class is getting loaded as a `Controller`? Your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` may not be getting picked up properly, and you haven't posted the startup logs.

Comment: I have added the complete log message to the question

Comment: Try adding a `@PostConstruct` method to your `SearchController` class that outputs a log message; I'm suspicious that it's not getting loaded.

Comment: You are right! My controller is not getting loaded. What can i do to get that loaded ?. I though my <mvc:annotation-driven /> and compnent scan loads the controller.

Comment: You should read up on how Spring loads application contexts. In this particular case, you either need to specifically add `dispatcher-context.xml` to your `web.xml` or try moving it to `WEB-INF/spring/`.

Comment: I have added contextloader listner to load my dispatcherservelt by still it is not loading the controller.

Comment: Did you move the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` into `WEB-INF/spring` or manually specify to load that context?

Comment: Currently my dispatcher servlet is in WEB-INF/ folder. I don't have any WEB-INF/srping folder

Comment: Right, and that's the problem. Spring is looking in `WEB-INF/spring` because you didn't tell it to look anywhere else. Move your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file there.

Comment: My understanding is that by default spring looks for dispatcher-servlet.xml in WEB-INF/  folder. I have added <init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param> to  web.xml but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's problem with URI. How you invokes this servlet?

Comment: can you explain me in more detail. I'm trying to access the default http:localhost:8080/EnhancedRoyaltyTool/  page

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check Dispatcher Servlet. If you also check it then,
simple way: you need not add External jars by Build path. Go to the project workspace by folder and directly copy downloaded jars and paste into:

```
WebContent>WEB-INF>lib>(here directly paste your jar files.)

-> stop your application server (like tomcat);
-> go to your IDE -> Select Project -> Clean Project builds
```

After that, you go to: run your project. I hope it works!