# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHelloWorld/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm creating a sample Spring MVC Web Application to print a Greeting
    Message. When I run the Project, it is displaying me HTTP Status 404 error.
    I'm using Eclipse IDE, and I have added all JARs of Spring Framework
    4.2.6(Since I'm confused which JARS exactly to configured) along with commons-
    logging-1.1.1 JAR. The code for my Project is as follows

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
<display-name>SpringMVCHelloWorld</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-  
  class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The code for spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">



<bean id="HandlerMapping"  
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">
</bean>
<bean name="/index.jsp" class="beans.HelloController">

</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"   
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/">
</property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp">
</property>

</bean>
</beans>
```

The code for HelloController.java

```
package beans;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;


public class HelloController implements Controller {


@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, 
HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
    mav.addObject("msg","Hi This is the First Spring MVC Application");

    return mav;
}

}
```

The code for HelloPage.jsp

```
${msg}
```

The Error Log is

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHelloWorld/] 
in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

Comment: not sure why u need xml..? use annotations, and find example of starting spring with annotations. Also, try googling spring boot <- quickstart to spring. Also there is special IDE, called Spring Tool Suite, which is special eclipse extension for this. good luck

Comment: @Sarief, Pls let me know whats wroing in that? and what should I need to do there to make that application work

Comment: @BalusC, I looked the same type of question, but couldn't get that. Thats why I posted, if u know the answer let me know

Comment: xml is deprecated in use, except for legacy code. It is not wrong, but I proposed to you to use latest technology which is much easier to manage.  Do you really need to do it xml way?

Comment: what is  the exact path of your jsp file ?  Location. Also remove the <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>. Annotate your controller as mentionned in the answer below. these are the basics of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with spring, you can have a `@Controller` or `@RestController` annotation at the top of your class rather than implementing controller then you do `@RequestMapping` to the url you want. thus you can have:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "SpringMVCHelloWorld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView helloWorldRequest(){
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
     mav.addObject("msg","Hi This is the First Spring MVC Application");
     return mav;
  }
}
```

you can map to other urls using different methods and the `@RequestMapping` annotation as well.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I tried your code but It is getting me "HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" error

Comment: @ShaikYakhoobAli check this out if it helps: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/61693-error-instantiating-servlet-class-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherservlet

Comment: @ShaikYakhoobAli see the solution in this post also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027619/org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherservlet-nohandlerfound-for-basic-sprin